# Deliver a WPF Browser Aplication as out of browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-browser

Is it possible to deliver a WPF application to an end user but display it out of browser when it gets there?

I've tried setting an option to allow the application to run offline but Visual Studio has blanked out that option for me...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF is supported via [ClickOnce](http://wpfandclickonce.codeplex.com/).  Silverlight can be hosted by the browser, and then stored for offline usage or [run entirely out of browser](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/out-of-browser-applications-%28silverlight-quickstart%29), as well.

Comment: The link about clickonce isn't really helping, under 'Publish' in the project options 'Install Mode and Settings' is blanked out so I can't choose 'The application is available offline as well'

Comment: The link includes a full video tutorial.  I would try following it with a new project, and reintroduce variables until you determine what is causing it to be blanked out.  The most common issue the project not being based off of the right template.  The VS2010 WPF Application template allows online and offline ClickOnce publishing.  Other templates may not.